# Google Datastore Long Query Time

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am working with Google Datastore to query a certain kind of entity that has 25 properties. I only have 5 entities in the Datastore of this kind, but when I query these entities, it takes an average of 2 seconds to create the new Query and 4 seconds to prepare the query. On subsequent fetches, it only takes 500ms for the whole process. I have two indexes on this kind of entity. Is there any way to improve the performance of the initial fetch?

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query q = new Query("Producers").setFilter(new FilterPredicate("name", FilterOperator.EQUAL, searchName));
List<Entity> producers = datastore.prepare(q).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```

Comment: Is it the initial query or the initial request to your instance after you deploy it? How do you distinguish "initial" query from "subsequent" query?

Comment: The initial query is when an instance is not running and needs to startup. The subsequent queries are when an instance is already running when the request is made.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is not related to your query, number of entities or indexes. Even if you reduce your code to `System.out.print("Hello!")`, it will take 6-8 seconds for your instance to startup and respond. Complex apps with code injection, etc., might take much longer.

If this startup time is critical for you, you can switch your scaling model from "Automatic" to "Basic" or "Manual", to make at least one instance always available. Even then you may face this issue when there is a need to start the second instance, etc., but the importance of this issue quickly dissipates with the number of instances (e.g. if running instances support 10,000 active users, only 10,001st user with experience this delay).

Also note that with automatic scaling instances shut up after ~15 minutes of inactivity. Again, if your app has enough users to never shut down, the vast majority of your users will never face this delay.